# How to customize SimpleHTTPServer to variable page size

Tags: python, http, tcp, mininet

I am writing a Python script for network (using [Mininet](http://mininet.org)) to simulate server-client TCP transmission. My question is: Can I customize `SimpleHTTPServer` so that I can specify the size of web page that will be transmitted to the client?

Comment: what do you mean "size of web page" ? size in bytes ? different page for PC and for mobile device ? You can use `random` to send different page or url with parameters - ie. `http://example.com/?size=small` or normally create different html files `http://example.com/small.html`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the page sent by SimpleHTTPServer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637002/how-to-customize-the-page-sent-by-simplehttpserver)